# XCode 4 Compiling Issues

Tags: xcode

I had a program that worked fine in Xcode 3 but when I imported the project in Xcode 4 I'm getting a lot of issues, I would like to know what causes this & how to fix it.
[image: Errors when code is copied into Xcode manually]

[image: Errors when project that was built & run successfully into Xcode 3 built into Xcode 4]

First one shows errors when code is copied into Xcode manually & the second one shows errors when project that was built & run successfully into Xcode 3 built into Xcode 4

Comment: Can you please show some examples?

Comment: I recompiled & the errors changed...XCode 4 is driving me insane >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I was trying to import the Foundation framework into a C project *facepalm
Thx for all the feedback & help

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it you are either not importing a header or linking against a framework. The errors are basically stating that the compiler cannot find the symbols you need. Check at the top of your file and see if you're importing the correct header. If you are and an error is being shown there then it is probably a linking issue, so check your project settings.

Comment: I only use 2 frameworks & I imported both of them from the build phase pane, the errors are found in the NSObjCRuntime.h NSZone.H & NSObject.h

Comment: What SDK are you compiling against? It could possibly be that the SDK you have selected is no longer available.

Comment: I think the error occurred because I was trying to import an Obj C framework into a C project